# Ruby Page Object Gem - Sample Project

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby page object gem, I saw Git, the sample looks too complex.

Can someone share a sample code - say to

- > launch google
  ->  enter a search keyword
- > verify the results found

That would be of great help !

Comment: The example at e.g. https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Get-me-started-right-now%21 looks very simple, but incomplete. It may help if you explained what it is about the sample that is too complex for you. Then answers could focus on helping you with just the parts you need.

Comment: I am looking for a simple program with page object gem, can you help?                                                > launch google                                                       > enter a search keyword
> verify the results found

Comment: @fishspy, see my answer and rate if it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

I started to put together a sample project for [PageObject](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object)

https://github.com/JonKernPA/pageobject

Hope this helps